# AutoFac - Registering a decorator for some of an open Generic

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

I'm attempting to set up an Autofac module that seems to have a complicated requirement.

here goes:

I have a generic interface:

```cs
public interface IMyInterface<TFoo, TBar>
```

I have a bunch of classes that implement this interface

e.g.

```cs
class MyImpl1 : IMyInterface<string, bool> { }
class MyImpl2 : IMyInterface<bool, string> { }
class MyImpl3 : IMyInterface<bool, string> { }
```

Finally, I have a decorator:

```cs
class MyDecorator<TFoo, TBar> : IMyInterface<TFoo, TBar>
```

I only want to "Decorate" the implementations (of `MyInterface`) that have a particular attribute. So all implementations of MyInterface that have an Attribute of `[MyAttribute]` 
are decorated with MyDecorator.

I'm close but no cigar yet:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();        

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes(true)
        .Any(attr => attr.GetType() == typeof(MyAttribute)))
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof (IMyInterface<,>))
    .Keyed("CachableQueries", typeof(IMyInterface<,>));

builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(MyDecorator<,>),
    typeof(IMyInterface<,>), "CachableQueries");

var container = builder.Build();

Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<IMyInterface<string,bool>>());
Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<IMyInterface<bool,bool>>());
```

I understand that the final piece of the puzzle is the Key, it actually need to pass the type into the `Keyed("CachableQueries", THE_TYPE);` but its not playing ball.

**Update**

nemesv sent me in the right direction.

As part of my question, I forgot to mention that I also needed to register all the implementations of IMyInterface<,> that didn't have the [MyAttribute].

I did this in two stages. First Register the types with the Decorator and then register the rest.

My Solution:
I know it needs refactoring, but as a proof of concept. it works.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //Get all the types we're interested in (that inherit IMyInterface)
        List<Type> typesToQuery = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
            .Where(type => type.GetInterfaces()
                    .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IMyInterface<,>))).ToList();

        //Even tho the decorator inherits IMyInterface (we don't want to process it)
        typesToQuery.Remove(typeof (MyDecorator<,>)); 


        //build a dictionary of all the types, so we don't process them again.
        Dictionary<Type, bool> typesToProcess = typesToQuery.ToDictionary(queryType => queryType, queryType => false);


        //Register all types that have [MyAttribute]
        foreach (var type in typesToQuery
                    .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                    .Any(attr => attr.GetType() == (typeof(MyAttribute)))))
        {
            builder.RegisterType(type).Keyed("CachableQueries",
                type.GetInterfaces()
                    .First(i =>
                            i.IsGenericType &&
                            i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMyInterface<,>)));

            typesToProcess[type] = true; //update, so this type isn't processed again
        }

        //Decorate the correct ones
        builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(typeof(MyDecorator<,>), typeof(IMyInterface<,>), fromKey: "CachableQueries");

        //Register the rest of the types we're interested 
        foreach (Type type in typesToProcess.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == false).Select(pair => pair.Key))
        {
            builder.RegisterType(type).As(
                type.GetInterfaces()
                    .First(i =>
                            i.IsGenericType &&
                            i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMyInterface<,>)));

        } 

        var container = builder.Build();

        Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<IMyInterface<string, bool>>());
        Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<IMyInterface<bool, bool>>());

        //Result:
        //AutoFacPlay.MyDecorator`2[System.String,System.Boolean]  - this one was decorated (as it has MyAttribute)
        //AutoFacPlay.MyImplementation2 - this one wasn't decorated

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18000522/register-autofac-decorator-for-only-one-generic-command-handler

Comment: close :) i'm working with open generic interfaces. In that example the decorator is decided by a specific type. My scenario is decided by an attribute. I won't be moving over to SimpleInjector (not my decision) :P

Comment: (I can never get the code indicator to work in the WYSIWYG editor!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you are using the `Keyed` registration then you need to specify the closed service type e.g. `IMyInterface<string, bool>` so you cannot use an open generic there like `typeof(IMyInterface<,>)`

However because when using the `RegisterAssemblyTypes` there is no API where you could get the currently registered closed type in order to register it as `Keyed`. So you need to implement the "assembly scanning" by hand:

You need to replace your `RegisterAssemblyTypes` call with something like this (you probably need some more error handling in production):

```
foreach (var type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
    .Where(type => type.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                       .Any(attr => attr.GetType() == (typeof(MyAttribute)))))
{
     builder.RegisterType(type).Keyed("CachableQueries",
         type.GetInterfaces()
             .First(i => 
                    i.IsGenericType && 
                    i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMyInterface<,>)));
}
```

This is equivalent to the following manual registration which is required for the `RegisterGenericDecorator` to work (assuming that `MyImpl1` and `MyImpl3` was marked with the `MyAttribute`:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyImpl1>()
       .Keyed<IMyInterface<string, bool>>("CachableQueries");
builder.RegisterType<MyImpl3>()
       .Keyed<IMyInterface<bool, bool>>("CachableQueries");
```

Note you cannot use `RegisterGeneric` here because you have this special `MyAttribute` filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nemesv, it put me on the correct track. I an inklien i would need to break open the raw reflection code to get this working. :)

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I didn't realise the question was from 3 years ago as it was updated just a week ago.

We can take advantage of the chained methods during registration to segregate types that are decorated with the attribute from those that are not.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Autofac;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public interface IOpenGeneric<T, U>
    {
        U Get(T value);
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class DecorateAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }

    [Decorate]
    public class BooleanToStringOne : IOpenGeneric<bool, string>
    {
        public string Get(bool value)
        {
            return $"{value.ToString()} from BooleanToStringOne";
        }
    }

    [Decorate]
    public class BooleanToStringTwo : IOpenGeneric<bool, string>
    {
        public string Get(bool value)
        {
            return $"{value.ToString()} from BooleanToStringTwo";
        }
    }

    public class BooleanToStringThree : IOpenGeneric<bool, string>
    {
        public string Get(bool value)
        {
            return $"{value.ToString()} from BooleanToStringThree";
        }
    }

    public class OpenGenericDecorator<T, U> : IOpenGeneric<T, U>
    {
        private readonly IOpenGeneric<T, U> _inner;

        public OpenGenericDecorator(IOpenGeneric<T, U> inner)
        {
            _inner = inner;
        }

        public U Get(T value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{_inner.GetType().Name} is being decorated!");
            return _inner.Get(value);
        }
    }

    public static class ReflectionExtensions
    {
        public static bool HasAttribute<TAttribute>(this Type type)
            where TAttribute : Attribute
        {
            return type
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TAttribute), false)
                .Cast<Attribute>()
                .Any();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // associate types that have the [Decorate] attribute with a specific key
            builder
                .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
                .Where(x => x.HasAttribute<DecorateAttribute>())
                .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IOpenGeneric<,>), "decoratable-service");

            // get the keyed types and register the decorator
            builder.RegisterGenericDecorator(
                typeof(OpenGenericDecorator<,>),
                typeof(IOpenGeneric<,>),
                "decoratable-service");

            // no key for the ones with no [Decorate] attribute so they'll
            // get resolved "as is"
            builder
                .RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
                .Where(x => !x.HasAttribute<DecorateAttribute>())
                .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IOpenGeneric<,>));

            var container = builder.Build();

            var booleanToStrings = container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IOpenGeneric<bool,string>>>();
            foreach (var item in booleanToStrings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Get(true));
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output from the console is

```
BooleanToStringTwo is being decorated!
True from BooleanToStringTwo

BooleanToStringOne is being decorated!
True from BooleanToStringOne

True from BooleanToStringThree
```